# Is 66,200 results in google good for a start up content based website

Tags: google, search-engines, seo

Is 66,200 results in google good for a start up QnA content based website.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe. It depends on how many pages exist in your wesbsite. If you have 66,200 pages then that is good. If you have millions then that's not so good.

Keep in mind that pages indexed do not directly correlate to good rankings. Also, the number of pages indexed has nothing to do with the content or format of the website.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several factors including how many pages total you have, and how long the site has been around. The key metric to look at is whether Google is finding and indexing your best content - i.e. your most popular/upvoted questions and answers.

If you got 66k pages indexed in a couple of months then that is very good. If you have 1 million pages and the site has been around over a year then that's maybe not so good. Make sure your navigation is clear and simple, and that you have an XML sitemap listing all your pages.

Also note that if you opened your site with thousands or millions of pages it's possible Google is keeping your site in some kind of "sandbox" to ensure it's not a spam site or content farm.